# Initialize byte array using string

Tags: go

Salsa20 requires a `key *[32]byte` which I want to provide using a string constant.
Passing the key using a type-cast to a slice yield `error: argument 4 has incompatible type`. I don't know of any way to cast a string (or a slice) as an array.

I don't want to create  variable `byteKey [32]byte` and use `copy([:]byteKey, []byte(stringKey))` every time the encryption takes place.

This is my current solution:

```
func createFeedbackKey() (key [32]byte) {
  const s = "thesingleonegreatairfysecretword"
  copy(key[:], s)
  return
}

var feedbackKey = createFeedbackKey()
```

That's 6 lines of code with a copy where, imho, a mere typecast should suffice.

Is there a shorter/better way?
Something like this maybe?

```
var key = [...]byte("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
```

Comment: @tim cooper
Can you explain why this is a duplicate?
My problem isn't solved by using a variable.
I want to initialize an array of bytes using a string.

Comment: `[...]` doesn't help unless the bytes are specified individually.

Comment: There is no such thing as a constant array in Go, so your question cannot be answered. Read the linked question and try posting another question that isn't about constant arrays.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explaining.
I included the `const` aspect in my original question to better describe what i want to achive conceptually.